# Boot folder is full so cannot install updates.

Tags: boot

Plenty of free disk space. How do I either free up space on boot or increase its size? Using release 12.10 (quantal) 64-bit Kernel Linux 3.5.0-26-generic.  Thanks, Dave.

Comment: By reading this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot ;)

Answer (score 13):

**Delete the old Kernels**

```
sudo apt-get purge $( dpkg --list | grep -P -o "linux-image-\d\S+" | grep -v $(uname -r | grep -P -o ".+\d") )
```

OR

**use Ubuntu tweaks and then run janitor to clear unused packages**

http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Comment: As of 7-28-2015, the latest version of Ubuntu Tweak (http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2014/04/21/ubuntu-tweak-0-8-7-released-14-04-ready.html) is over a year old and was designed for 14.04. Current release is 15.04.